# Use Keycloak with react native

Tags: react-native, authentication, keycloak

I'm developing an app for ios and android in react native and need to use keycloak for authorization, but struggling to find a good way.

I've tried react-native-app-auth and it works good to sign in but not to sign out. 
Not so strange because react-native-app-auth states that: "Keycloak does not specify a revocation endpoint so revoke functionality doesn't work."

I've had a look at a few other npm packages such as react-native-login-keycloak but they seem to lack maintenance and opens a lot of browser tabs.

Any ideas of how to solve this or maybe do a work-around for react-native-app-auth?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the openid-connect configuration endpoint.

You can find it in your keycloak server

`https://{your-keycloak-server}/auth/realms/{your_realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration`

you will find the endpoints for:

`authorization_endpoint`
`token_endpoint`
`end_session_endpoint`

Add those to your react-native-app-auth configuration.

Comment: I just tried this. It looked very promising but but i get  "ok": false, "status": 400, "statusText": undefined from the revoke function in react-native-app-auth.
Revoke preforms a POST, is that right?

Comment: App-auth missed too many things, register, logout, token refresh and so on....